Performance Comparison between select() and .withColumn()/.withColumns() in PySpark
I'm looking to optimize data transformations in PySpark and noticed the documentation advises using .select() over multiple .withColumn() calls for better performance. This raises two questions regarding the performance of .withColumns() (the version that adds multiple columns, from a map. It was introduced in version 3.3.0):

Does .withColumns() encounter the same performance drawbacks as sequential .withColumn() calls?
How does .withColumns() compare to .select() in terms of efficiency when adding or transforming multiple columns?


withColumns performs an additional analysis check on the columns to remove or replace.  select does not, as such it'll be faster but it may not be the correct result for your use case.
While this check is not as heavy as writing a file out it is still an action and forces evaluation.
"it'll be faster" - this is really dependent on how complicated your expression tree is and if files need to be read (parquet can really suffer under this, delta won't).  It is definitely more convenient to use withColumns if you don't know the current schema (evaluating the schema to do this yourself ends up with the same performance hit).
